# Unable to Resize Column Contents according to the values of the column

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtablewidget, qtablewidgetitem

I have a table which is being populated by the Database (MySQL) at the backend.

I am trying to resize the Columns according to the contents of each column (as much the stretch is possible), however I can't seem to do it.

I looked it up on Stackoverflow and found that I can do it by setting the `QScrollAbstractArea.sizeAdjustPolicy` to `AdjustToContents` in the Qt Designer.

I did this but it still did not work.

I further looked it up and found different solutions. One of them was this as well but it also did not work for me,

```
self.ui.course_table.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(0, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.Stretch)
        self.ui.course_table.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(1, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
        self.ui.course_table.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(2, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
```

I have shared a picture of my current table right now and I want to expand each column according to the content I have.

[image]

As you can see, there is a lot of space that can be stretched but it is not doing it despite having enough space. **Even the Column names are not fully visible and some characters are cut off**

In `not maximized window` form, this is what I get

[image]

As for my data, it is coming from MySQL database and it is attached to Button Click (whenever I click on the "Courses" button on the side menu, it will populate the data on the table in the Courses Page)

The function that is populating the table is as follows,

```
def get_course_data(self):
        mycursor = self.DB.cursor() # DB is an object of class
        Subquery = "Select course_name, course_code, course_type from tbl_course"
        mycursor.execute(Subquery)

        numcols = len(mycursor.fetchall()[0])
        mycursor.execute(Subquery)
        numrows = len(mycursor.fetchall())
        self.ui.course_table.setRowCount(numrows)
        self.ui.course_table.setColumnCount(numcols+1)
        mycursor.execute(Subquery)
        tablerow = 0
        for row in mycursor.fetchall():
            tablecol = 0
            layout = QHBoxLayout()
            layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
            layout.setSpacing(0)
            delete_button = QPushButton()
            icon_delete = QIcon()
            icon_delete.addFile(u":/icons/icons/Delete-button.png", QSize(), QIcon.Normal, QIcon.Off)
            delete_button.setIcon(icon_delete)
            layout.addWidget(delete_button)
            edit_button = QPushButton()
            index = PySide2.QtCore.QPersistentModelIndex(self.ui.course_table.model().index(tablerow, tablecol))
            edit_button.clicked.connect(lambda *args, index=index: self.on_course_edit_click())
            icon_edit = QIcon()
            icon_edit.addFile(u":/icons/icons/edit-button.png", QSize(), QIcon.Normal, QIcon.Off)
            edit_button.setIcon(icon_edit)
            layout.addWidget(edit_button)
            cellWidget = QWidget()
            cellWidget.setLayout(layout)
            
            self.ui.course_table.setCellWidget(tablerow, 3, cellWidget)
            while tablecol < numcols:
                self.ui.course_table.setItem(tablerow, tablecol, PySide2.QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(row[tablecol])))
                tablecol += 1
            tablerow += 1
        
        self.ui.course_table.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(0, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.Stretch)
        self.ui.course_table.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(1, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
        self.ui.course_table.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(2, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
```

The layout of this page of mine is as follows, (it basically has three frames who are in horizontal layout and the third frame contains the QTableWidget. The third frame's `sizePolicy` is set to `Expanding` so that it covers the whole main body while the two other performs are aligned to the top of the main body)

[image]

The `.ui` file (for only the course widget) is as follows

```
            <widget class="QWidget" name="courses_page">
             <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_12">
              <item alignment="Qt::AlignLeft|Qt::AlignTop">
               <widget class="QFrame" name="frame_13">
                <property name="frameShape">
                 <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
                </property>
                <property name="frameShadow">
                 <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
                </property>
                <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_12">
                 <item alignment="Qt::AlignLeft">
                  <widget class="QLabel" name="label_4">
                   <property name="font">
                    <font>
                     <family>Arial</family>
                     <pointsize>12</pointsize>
                     <weight>75</weight>
                     <bold>true</bold>
                    </font>
                   </property>
                   <property name="text">
                    <string>Courses Page</string>
                   </property>
                  </widget>
                 </item>
                </layout>
               </widget>
              </item>
              <item alignment="Qt::AlignTop">
               <widget class="QFrame" name="frame_14">
                <property name="frameShape">
                 <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
                </property>
                <property name="frameShadow">
                 <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
                </property>
                <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_13">
                 <item alignment="Qt::AlignLeft">
                  <widget class="QFrame" name="frame_16">
                   <property name="frameShape">
                    <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
                   </property>
                   <property name="frameShadow">
                    <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
                   </property>
                   <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_14">
                    <item>
                     <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_2">
                      <property name="font">
                       <font>
                        <family>Calibri</family>
                        <pointsize>10</pointsize>
                       </font>
                      </property>
                      <property name="styleSheet">
                       <string notr="true">:hover
{
color: red;
font-size: 150%;
}</string>
                      </property>
                      <property name="text">
                       <string>Add New</string>
                      </property>
                      <property name="icon">
                       <iconset resource="icons.qrc">
                        <normaloff>:/icons/icons/icons8-add-48.png</normaloff>:/icons/icons/icons8-add-48.png</iconset>
                      </property>
                      <property name="iconSize">
                       <size>
                        <width>24</width>
                        <height>24</height>
                       </size>
                      </property>
                     </widget>
                    </item>
                    <item>
                     <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_3">
                      <property name="font">
                       <font>
                        <family>Calibri</family>
                        <pointsize>10</pointsize>
                       </font>
                      </property>
                      <property name="text">
                       <string>Delete All</string>
                      </property>
                      <property name="icon">
                       <iconset resource="icons.qrc">
                        <normaloff>:/icons/icons/icons8-remove-48.png</normaloff>:/icons/icons/icons8-remove-48.png</iconset>
                      </property>
                      <property name="iconSize">
                       <size>
                        <width>24</width>
                        <height>24</height>
                       </size>
                      </property>
                     </widget>
                    </item>
                   </layout>
                  </widget>
                 </item>
                 <item alignment="Qt::AlignLeft">
                  <widget class="QFrame" name="frame_17">
                   <property name="frameShape">
                    <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
                   </property>
                   <property name="frameShadow">
                    <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
                   </property>
                   <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_15">
                    <item>
                     <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit">
                      <property name="font">
                       <font>
                        <family>Arial</family>
                        <pointsize>10</pointsize>
                       </font>
                      </property>
                      <property name="styleSheet">
                       <string notr="true">background-color: white;
border-bottom: 1px solid; 
color: black;</string>
                      </property>
                      <property name="placeholderText">
                       <string>Search Course</string>
                      </property>
                     </widget>
                    </item>
                    <item alignment="Qt::AlignLeft">
                     <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
                      <property name="text">
                       <string/>
                      </property>
                      <property name="icon">
                       <iconset resource="icons.qrc">
                        <normaloff>:/icons/icons/icons8-search-50.png</normaloff>:/icons/icons/icons8-search-50.png</iconset>
                      </property>
                      <property name="iconSize">
                       <size>
                        <width>24</width>
                        <height>24</height>
                       </size>
                      </property>
                     </widget>
                    </item>
                   </layout>
                  </widget>
                 </item>
                </layout>
               </widget>
              </item>
              <item>
               <widget class="QFrame" name="frame_15">
                <property name="sizePolicy">
                 <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Expanding">
                  <horstretch>0</horstretch>
                  <verstretch>0</verstretch>
                 </sizepolicy>
                </property>
                <property name="frameShape">
                 <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
                </property>
                <property name="frameShadow">
                 <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
                </property>
                <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_16">
                 <item>
                  <widget class="QTableWidget" name="course_table">
                   <property name="font">
                    <font>
                     <family>Arial</family>
                     <weight>50</weight>
                     <bold>false</bold>
                     <kerning>true</kerning>
                    </font>
                   </property>
                   <property name="styleSheet">
                    <string notr="true">:item
{
color: black;
}

QHeaderView:section
{
background-color: white;
font-weight: bold;
border: 0px;
}</string>
                   </property>
                   <property name="sizeAdjustPolicy">
                    <enum>QAbstractScrollArea::AdjustToContents</enum>
                   </property>
                   <property name="editTriggers">
                    <set>QAbstractItemView::NoEditTriggers</set>
                   </property>
                   <property name="alternatingRowColors">
                    <bool>true</bool>
                   </property>
                   <property name="gridStyle">
                    <enum>Qt::NoPen</enum>
                   </property>
                   <property name="sortingEnabled">
                    <bool>true</bool>
                   </property>
                   <property name="wordWrap">
                    <bool>true</bool>
                   </property>
                   <attribute name="horizontalHeaderMinimumSectionSize">
                    <number>47</number>
                   </attribute>
                   <attribute name="horizontalHeaderHighlightSections">
                    <bool>true</bool>
                   </attribute>
                   <attribute name="horizontalHeaderStretchLastSection">
                    <bool>false</bool>
                   </attribute>
                   <attribute name="verticalHeaderVisible">
                    <bool>false</bool>
                   </attribute>
                   <attribute name="verticalHeaderCascadingSectionResizes">
                    <bool>false</bool>
                   </attribute>
                   <attribute name="verticalHeaderMinimumSectionSize">
                    <number>28</number>
                   </attribute>
                   <attribute name="verticalHeaderHighlightSections">
                    <bool>true</bool>
                   </attribute>
                   <attribute name="verticalHeaderShowSortIndicator" stdset="0">
                    <bool>true</bool>
                   </attribute>
                   <attribute name="verticalHeaderStretchLastSection">
                    <bool>false</bool>
                   </attribute>
                   <row>
                    <property name="text">
                     <string>1</string>
                    </property>
                   </row>
                   <row>
                    <property name="text">
                     <string>2</string>
                    </property>
                   </row>
                   <column>
                    <property name="text">
                     <string>Course Name</string>
                    </property>
                   </column>
                   <column>
                    <property name="text">
                     <string>Course Code</string>
                    </property>
                   </column>
                   <column>
                    <property name="text">
                     <string>Course Type</string>
                    </property>
                   </column>
                   <column>
                    <property name="text">
                     <string>Action</string>
                    </property>
                   </column>
                   <item row="0" column="0">
                    <property name="text">
                     <string>Ha</string>
                    </property>
                   </item>
                   <item row="0" column="1">
                    <property name="text">
                     <string>111</string>
                    </property>
                   </item>
                   <item row="0" column="2">
                    <property name="text">
                     <string>1</string>
                    </property>
                   </item>
                   <item row="0" column="3">
                    <property name="text">
                     <string>aaa</string>
                    </property>
                   </item>
                   <item row="1" column="0">
                    <property name="text">
                     <string>assa</string>
                    </property>
                   </item>
                   <item row="1" column="1">
                    <property name="text">
                     <string>Programming Fundamentals</string>
                    </property>
                   </item>
                   <item row="1" column="2">
                    <property name="text">
                     <string>55</string>
                    </property>
                   </item>
                   <item row="1" column="3">
                    <property name="text">
                     <string>55</string>
                    </property>
                   </item>
                  </widget>
                 </item>
                </layout>
               </widget>
              </item>
             </layout>
            </widget>
```

The complete `interface.ui` code is given here: https://pastebin.com/bSEmRACT
(As an example, I have added two sample rows in the data)

The complete `interface.py` code is given here: https://pastebin.com/AA79ndcw

The code of `main.py` is also shared here: https://pastebin.com/EWNAmH6K

Comment: What do you mean by "not enlarged form"? Are you using layouts? How are you creating the UI? Are you setting size restraints on the table or its container? Why are you setting resize modes for the first three columns, while there are four? Please provide a [mre].

Comment: @musicamante I am using QT deisgner for UI. I have shared the .ui code for the "Courses Page" (please let me know if other is needed) and also added the layout structure picture for this page. I have not made any changes in the UI from the main.py file. I have not set any restraints on the table or the container (as far as I know). And for resize modes, I was only setting for first three because I was trying out a solution from another Stackoverflow question however it did not work for me (if it had worked, I would have resized all the four columns).

Comment: By "not enlarge form", I actually meant the window of the UI when it is `not maximized`. The table still is not fully stretched to cover the whole window in this not maximized window as well. Sorry for the poor English, it's not my first language and I could not find a proper word to express this "not maximized" window.

Comment: Sorry but that's *not* a reproducible example. Also, it seems to me that you're editing the file generated by pyuic, which is not something you should do. Share the ui file and an actual MRE.

Comment: @musicamante I'm sorry, I can't figure out how to provide the MRE for this example, really sorry for that :/ I have shared my complete .ui File using the pastebin and also the main.py (at the end of my post). I have only worked on QT Designer for the UI interface and haven't changed the file generated by pyuic at all. Also, my main.py file contains only the logical implementations and I didn't change the constraints of QTableWidget in that file. Which is why I am finding it a bit difficult to share the MRE (as my whole work is on QT Designer and not in coding)

Comment: No, you shared the pyuic file, I told you to share the `.ui` file. You should also add it to the question, not using an external resource (questions should be self-contained and persistent, your pastebin will expire in 2 weeks making the question invalid to other users). Remove the partial snippet taken from the pyuic file and replace it with the ui file.

Comment: @musicamante Oh, I got it! I have shared the ui file now for the `course widget` in the main post (instead of the snippet from pyuic file). Unfortunately, I can't post the complete ui code in the post (because of the characters limit) which is why I had to use pastebin (however, I have set the default settings of Pastebin links to never expire)